# Recommended way to build cross platform desktop application using linux development machine

Tags: python, linux, windows

I am pretty familiar with building web based apps using python django on my linux machine. But when I decided to try my hand at building desktop applications that can run on windows/linux I didn't know where to begin.

I know I can surely build windows desktop application on windows machine. But I am pretty comfortable with linux and don't want to get out of that comfort zone. Can anyone guide me as to what tools can I begin with to develop a simple windows desktop application. I would target windows 7 for starters.

Any guidance is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but questions asking for recommandations on a tool, framework or library are off topic on Stack Overflow. Anyway Anatzum already gave you the interesting information ...

Comment: Duly noted. But the experience of people on stack overflow helps a lot in making a decision in such cases. So I figured out it was the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a GUI tool-kit with bindings to python. Tkinter is the de facto standard for python GUI and is cross platform. Qt is also a popular choice but the license is more restrictive then Tkinter but will allow you to transition into C++ programming with Qt easier if that is something you may want to do down the road. The choice up to you.

Comment: Appreciated. Thank you. Would you recommend kivy for such requirements?

Comment: Apologies as I cant upvote the answer as I am still stuck on 14 rep.

Answer (score 1):

With python, I think your main options are:

- Tkinter, the GUI library included with Python.
- [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/), a wrapper for the cross-platform GUI API wxWidget.
- [Kivy](http://kivy.org/), another cross-platform GUI library.

If you only need a simple application, any of these libraries would be a good choice.

Comment: I visited the website for kivy, it seemed elegant and a good option but would it be a good choice for building an application with some crud operations, report generation may be?

Comment: Apologies as I cant upvote the answer as I am still stuck on 14 rep.

Comment: I do not know for Kivy, but for wxPython you have [pdfviewer](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/lib.pdfviewer.html) to display and print PDF files.